# Проблема при установке tasksel на Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Добрый день. После установки tasksel, запускаю сам tasksel, отмечаю необходимые компоненты и на этом все. Tasksel вылетает.

Comment: Экстрасенсов не существует, но существуют логи.

Comment: @matz а какие именно логи нужны? в папке log много файлов.

Comment: @matz ebconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: Permission denied
tasksel: debconf failed to run